# What is the safe way of using keyword-only arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Keyword-only arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965271/forced-naming-of-parameters-in-python) are arguments that can only be supplied to a function by keyword. In Python they are defined by a single asterisk in a function's signature. For example:

```
>>> def foo(bar, *, baz):
        print(bar, baz)
>>> foo(1, baz=2)
    1 2
>>> foo(1, 2)
TypeError: foo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Using them has not only stylistic advantages and disadvantages but functional as well. Here are some that I'm aware of:

Advantages:

- It's less error-prone. When having positional arguments in a function call, changing a signature can break things. With keyword-only arguments there is no such a problem. (https://bugs.python.org/issue26729, https://bugs.python.org/issue18726, https://bugs.python.org/issue25628)

And disadvantages:

- Making all arguments keyword-only won't allow to use the function with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map). For example:

  ```
  >>> def square(*, x):
          return x * 2

  >>> list(map(square, [1, 2, 3]))
  TypeError: square() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
  ```

I couldn't find a general description on how I should properly use the keyword-only arguments in [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) that proposed them in the first place or in any other sources.

So, my questions are: Are there any other pitfalls that I'm unaware of when using keyword-only arguments? How can I safely use them without potentially break something in the future?

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, language features have pitfalls, costs, and benefits. The core point of programming language style guides (such as [Google Style Guides](http://google.github.io/styleguide/)) and [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do) is to avoid features or uses that are surprising, error-prone, tricky, or hard to maintain.

Here are some good cases for keyword-only args:

- Options that are non-obvious at the call site, esp. boolean flags and multiple options. For [io.open()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/io.html#io.open), it would be reasonable (except for backwards compatibility) to make all the arguments after `file` and `mode` be keyword-only:
  `io.open(file, 'r', 0, None, '', '', False)`
- Arguments that are not easy to keep straight:
  `def address(*, country, administrative_area, sub_administrative_area, locality, dependent_locality, postal_code, thoroughfare, premise)`
- Arguments that you want to require callers to pass explicitly:
  `def delete(base, *, recursive)`
- Options to a function that also takes varargs:
  `def send(topic, message, *values, debug=True)`
- Options to a function that might well take varargs in the future. This is definitely a judgement call. The point is adding a varargs parameter will break any callers that pass an option as a positional parameter. Defining the options as keyword-only parameters reserves the ability to add a varags parameter.
  `def send(topic, message, *, debug=True)`

Here are some cases to not use keyword-only args:

- Code that needs to be compatible with Python 2.
- Generic functional programming: `map()`, `filter()`, `apply()`, ...
- One-argument functions: `repr(object)`.
- Varargs: `max(x, y, z, t)`.
- Where keyword-only args would add verbosity and clutter to no advantage: `bitwise_and(x1, x2)`. [`numpy.bitwise_and()` takes those two arguments and a bunch of optional arguments that are fair game for keyword-only, except for compatibility.]

and some other pitfalls of keyword-only args:

- It's yet another feature for new team members to learn when they're coming up to speed on Python and your code base.
- Extra complexity and distraction in the function definition. (What's that `*`?)
- Some dev tools might not handle it well: syntax highlighters, diff tools, refactoring editors, code inspectors, C interop, RPC (remote procedure call) code generators, ...
- Language features can interact with each other in surprising ways. "Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away." -- Antoine de Saint-Exupery.

Answer (score 2):

Keyword-only arguments are just a *tool* and there is no *one perfect tool for everything*. When it doesn't work, like in case of *map*, you use positional arguments.

You can use keyword-only arguments safely. Changing code, refactoring, is common way of handling with *worries about future*. Instead of predicting future you adapt past to current needs.

Best practice for keyword-only arguments is answer of Personal preferences and Software design.

Random result from internet search:
**4 Best Practices for Function Arguments**
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2314818

Answer (score 1):

There are no special disadvantages to using keyword-only arguments.

True, your function will have a different signature to ones with positional arguments and thus wont work with other functions that expect to be passed functions which match a particular signature.

But that is true for any incompatible change in signature and is easily worked around by wrapping your function.

You could if you wished also write a map function which inspects the arguments and uses the first keyword argument, when this case occurs.

Although I think I would argue that it is nonsensical for a function with a single argument to force the use of a keyword and throwing the error makes as much sense as implementing this behavior.